# c++ template function argument deduce and function resolution

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, resolution

Today I just want to raise a question on C++ template function argument deduce and template function overload resolution in c++ 11 (I am using vs2010 sp1). 
  I have defined two template functions as below:

function #1:

```
template <class T>
void func(const T& arg)
{
    cout << "void func(const T&)" <<endl;
}
```

function #2:

```
template <class T>
void func(T&& arg)
{
   cout << "void func(T&&)" <<endl;
}
```

Now consider the following code:

```
int main() {
    //I understand these first two examples:

    //function #2 is selected, with T deduced as int&
    //If I comment out function #2, function#1 is selected with
    //T deduced as int
    {int a = 0; func(a);}

    //function #1 is selected, with T is deduced as int.
    //If I comment out function #1, function #2 is selected,
    //with T deduced as const int&.
    {const int a = 0; func(a);}

    //I don't understand the following examples:  

    //Function #2 is selected... why?
    //Why not function #1 or ambiguous...
    {func(0);}

    //But here function #1 is selected.
    //I know the literal string “feng” is lvalue expression and
    //T is deduced as “const char[5]”. The const modifier is part
    //of the T type not the const modifier in “const T&” declaration. 
    {func(“feng”)}

    //Here function#2 is selected in which T is deduced as char(&)[5]
    {char array[] = “feng”; func(array);}
}
```

I just want to know the rules behind guiding the function overloading resolution under these scenarios.

I don't agree with the two answers below.I think the const int example is different from the literal string example. I can modify the #function 1 a bit to see what’s the deduced type on earth

```
 template <class T>
 void func(const T& arg)
 {
    T local;
    local = 0;
    cout << "void func(const T&)" <<endl;
 }
 //the compiler compiles the code happily 
 //and it justify that the T is deduced as int type
 const int a = 0;
 func(a);

 template <class T>
 void func(const T& arg)
 {
T local;
Local[0] = ‘a’;
cout << "void func(const T&)" <<endl;
 }
 //The compiler complains that “error C2734: 'local' : const object must be     
 //initialized if not extern
 //see reference to function template instantiation 
 //'void func<const char[5]>(T (&))' being compiled
  //    with
  //    [
  //        T=const char [5]
  //    ]

 Func(“feng”);
```

in the const int example, the const modifier in the “const T&” declaration eats up “the constness” of const int; while in the literal string example, I don’t know where the const modifier in the  “const T&” declaration goes. It is meaningless to declare some like int& const (but it is meaningful to declare int* const)

Comment: I've modified your question to make it a lot more readable, but I dropped out some sections that I could not understand. Please read through the new version and re-add anything that you think is important (and that I missed).

Comment: @Leonid: What are you smoking? You want a *non-const lvalue* to be deduced to be an rvalue reference? That's insanity. T deduced as `int&` is perfectly correct.

Comment: @DeadMG - you are correct, it is deduced as `int&`.  I've cut and pasted from what was printing by `func()` without thinking about it.

Answer (score 5):

The trick here is the `const`. Both F1 and F2 can accept any value of any type, but F2 is a better match in general, because it's perfect forwarding. So unless the value is a `const` lvalue, F2 is the best match. However, when the lvalue is `const`, F1 is the better match. This is why it's preferred for the const int and the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Note that overload #2 is exact match for T& and T&&. So both overloads can bind to rvalue and lvalue.  In your examples overload differentiation is done mostly on constness.

```
//Function #2 is selected... why?
//Why not function #1 or ambiguous...
{func(0);}
```

`0` is `int&&` - exact match for `T&&`

```
//But here function #1 is selected.
//I know the literal string “feng” is lvalue expression and
//T is deduced as “const char[5]”. The const modifier is part
//of the T type not the const modifier in “const T&” declaration. 
{func(“feng”)}
```

Literal `"feng"`  is `const char(&)[5]` - exact match for `const T&` in 1st overload. The  `(&)` indicates that this is a reference.

```
//Here function#2 is selected in which T is deduced as char(&)[5]
{char array[] = “feng”; func(array);}
```

array - is `char(&)[5]` - exact match for `T&` in 2nd overload

Comment: I expected `{func(0);}` to take the `const T&` version. Why is `T&&` picked? T is `const int` in this case.

Comment: No, `0` is `int&&` - standard says so.

Comment: i don't agree with you.i have supplement some evidence.