# Why do arrays of const preferentially bind to const T& parameters instead of T&& parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

It's generally a bad idea to overload a function template taking a "T&&" parameter, because that can bind to anything, but let's suppose we do it anyway:

```
template<typename T>
void func(const T& param)
{
  std::cout << "const T&\n";
}

template<typename T>
void func(T&& param)
{
  std::cout << "T&&\n";
}
```

My understanding has been that the `const T&` overload will get called for arguments that are const lvalues, and the `T&&` overload will get called for all other argument types.  But consider what happens when we call `func` with arrays of const and non-const contents:

```
int main()
{
  int array[5] = {};
  const int constArray[5] = {};

  func(array);             // calls T&& overload
  func(constArray);        // calls const T& overload
}
```

VC10, VC11, and gcc 4.7 agree on the results shown.  My question is why the second call invokes the `const T&` overload.  The simple answer is that `constArray` has a const in it, but I think that's too simple.  The type T that is deduced (regardless of the template selected) is "array of 5 const ints" so the type of `param` in the `const T&` overload would be "reference to const array of 5 const ints".  But the array named constArray is not itself declared const.  So why doesn't the call to `func(constArray)` invoke the `T&&` overload, thus yielding a type for `param` of "reference to array of 5 const ints"?

This question is motivated by the discussion associated with the question at [c++ template function argument deduce and function resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258608/c-template-function-argument-deduce-and-function-resolution), but I think that thread got sidetracked on other issues and did not clarify the question I'm now asking here.

Comment: That is because of reference collapsing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In function parameter lists (as well as everywhere else), a cv qualification on an array type is shuffled right to qualify the array element type.  For example, with `T = int [5]`, `const T &` is converted to `int const (&) [5]`.

> #### 3.9.3 CV-qualiﬁers [basic.type.qualiﬁer]
>
> 2 - [...] Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type (8.3.4).

So the call to `func` with an argument of type `int const [5]` is deduced as a call to either of:

```
void func<int [5]>(int const (&) [5])
void func<int const (&) [5]>(int const (& &&) [5])
// where the above collapses to
// 'void func<int const (&) [5]>(int const (&) [5])'
```

Both overloads are viable, but the former is preferred:

Let T1 be the `const T &` template and T2 be the `T &&` template; that is, their parameter types are T1 := `const T &` and T2 := `T &&`.  Then the transformed argument types (14.5.6.2:3) can be written A1 := `const C &`, A2 := `D &&` for synthesized types `C`, `D`.

Now, we attempt to order T1 against T2 (14.8.2.4:2), first using A1 as the argument template and P2 as the parameter template.  We remove references (14.8.2.4:5) giving A1 -> `const C` and T2 -> `T`, then remove cv-qualification (14.8.2.4:7) giving A1 -> `C` and T2 -> `T`.  The template `T` can be deduced to `C` (14.8.2.4:8) so *A1 is at least as specialised as P2*; conversely, A2 -> `D` -> `D`, P1 -> `const T` -> `T`, and `T` can be deduced to `D`, so *A2 is at least as specialised as P1*.

This would usually imply that neither is more specialised than the other; however, because the `P` and `A` types are reference types 14.8.2.4:9 applies, and since A1 is an lvalue reference and P2 is not, T1 is considered more specialized than T2.  (A tie between reference types can also be broken by cv-qualification under the same clause.)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the proper place in the standard that addresses this.  I was looking at the reference-initialization rules, which is nowhere near the right place. (I now see that the same information is in 8.3.4/1.)

Comment: Both overloads have identical signature. Why is one preferable? The answer must have something to do with the partial ordering of template specialisations, but I'm struggling to piece the argument together.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I agree, it would be nice to see this spelled out, because both templates accept both const and non-const lvalues and rvalues.  Intuitively, the T&& version seems less specialized than the const T& version, and that's consistent with the behavior of the compilers I cited, but a less hand-wavy explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: I have to back up a bit - I think partial ordering is actually not involved (since both templates have the same number of template arguments); rather, it is a (simpler) question of which specialisation is more specialised.

Comment: @KerrekSB the key rule is 14.8.2.4:9 (rvalue references are less specialized than lvalue references).  I've run through the partial ordering algorithm above.

Comment: @ecatmur: Brilliant, that's great! This is actually really involved. Thanks for spelling it out!

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing rvalue references (like `int&&`) and universal references (which are made from temp­late parameters, as in `template <typename T> ... T&&`).

Rvalue references indeed don't bind to lvalues. But universal references bind to anything. The question is just who's a better match.

The type you have is `int const [5]`. Now let's see:

- against `T const &`: Matches with `T = int[5]`.
- against `T &&`: Matches with `T = int const (&)[5]`.

The former is a better match, in the following sense: Both templates produce identical overloads. But `T = int[5]` is **more specialised** than `T = int const (&)[5]`. You can see this because `T = int const (&)[5]` can be realised as `T = U const &` with `U = int[5]`.

Note that to bind an lvalue to a universal reference, the type itself has to be deduced as a reference type.

(Obviously `array` doesn't match `const T &`, because it is not const. It can only match `T&&`, dedu­cing `T = int (&)[5]`).

Comment: *Clearly the former is a better match!*. Do you think it is *that* clear? I don't think so.

Comment: @Nawaz: "Clearly" = "Someone should look up the deduction ranking rules". But yes, the two differ by a CV conversion, which adds "1" to the metric.

Comment: @Nawaz: The real question is who would win between `T &&` and `T const &&`: I think binding-to-reference counts as an immediate match, so my bet is that that would be ambiguous.

Comment: Why is the T deduced to be int[5]?  The const is not top-level, hence should not be stripped off, IMO.  I believe that T should be deduced to be const int[5] for the const T& template.  I agree with you that for the T&& template, the deduced type is const int (&)[5].  Can you explain why you believe the const that applies to the contents of the array (*not* to the array itself) will be stripped off during type deduction?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: Ahh, I had misunderstood your question. OK, you've got the answer to that from the other answer. But what matters here is not the argument deduction (which we've settled), but the question which specialization is *more specialized*.